# How can I join strings in Go template without template functions?

Tags: go, templates

I have a string slice, like `x := []string{a,b,c}`, and eventually I want it to be like `a+"/"+b+"/"+c`.

The problem I'm trying to deal with is coming from the Go template.
I want to have a solution in Go template.

The following is my current solution, but it's obviously ugly.

```
res := {{range item := .x}}item+"/"{{end}}
res = res[:len(res)-1]
```

If you have better approaches, appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code to join a slice with `/`:

```
{{range $i, $v := .x}}{{if $i}}/{{end}}{{$v}}{{end}}
```

[Run the example on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z52gKftK8Xg).

Comment: wonderful, I have to say! It's a good way to join when `.x` is not a []string, but a []struct{string}

Comment: BTW, if I want to iterate a slice but the last one, like `range x[:len(x)-1]`. Can I implement it in go template? I don't want to use `funcmap` because it is binded to a type, like `[]string, []int`.  In fact, I want to join a slice[:len(slice)-1].